# InDesign: Use scripting to convert page to JPEG and place it on that same page

Tags: scripting, flash-cs5, adobe-indesign

How should I use CS5 scripting to convert the current InDesign page to an image and place it, tagged on that same page.

I have downloaded to reference and if provided pointers to a couple of the methods to use I could suss it out myself thereafter.

## Edit

- Place back into the current page (if your pages are numbered normally)
- Export to the current user's application directory

> ```
> var doc = app.activeDocument;
>
> app.jpegExportPreferences.properties = {
>    antiAlias: true,
>    embedColorProfile: true,
>    exportResolution: 150,
>    // exportingSpread: true, // Uncomment if spreads
>    jpegColorSpace: JpegColorSpaceEnum.rgb,
>    jpegExportRange: ExportRangeOrAllPages.exportRange,
>    jpegQuality: JPEGOptionsQuality.maximum,
>    jpegRenderingStyle: JPEGOptionsFormat.baselineEncoding,
>    useDocumentBleeds: false,
>    simulateOverprint: false,
>    pageString: app.activeWindow.activePage.name // Page(s) to export, must be a string
> }
>
> var userFolder = Folder ( Folder.userData.absoluteURI + "/Brilliant" );
>
> if (!userFolder.exists) userFolder.create();
>
> var tempFile = File(userFolder+"/page.jpg");
>
> doc.exportFile(ExportFormat.jpg, tempFile);
>
> var pageNumber = parseInt(app.activeWindow.activePage.name)-1?parseInt(app.activeWindow.activePage.name)-1:0;
>
> var pageToPlace = doc.pages[pageNumber].place(tempFile);
>
> tempFile.remove();
> ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a sample that might do what you are looking for. There's no easy way to save a jpg directly in an InDesign document, but you can export it to a temporary file and then place it back in. You might have to tune things a little bit to get things right but something like this should do the trick.

```
var doc = app.activeDocument;

// Set JPEG export preferences
app.jpegExportPreferences.properties = {
   antiAlias: true,
   embedColorProfile: true,
   exportResolution: 150,
   // exportingSpread: true, // Uncomment if spreads
   jpegColorSpace: JpegColorSpaceEnum.rgb,
   jpegExportRange: ExportRangeOrAllPages.exportRange,
   jpegQuality: JPEGOptionsQuality.maximum,
   jpegRenderingStyle: JPEGOptionsFormat.baselineEncoding,
   useDocumentBleeds: false,
   simulateOverprint: false,
   pageString: "1" // Page(s) to export, must be a string
}

// Make a temporary file
var tempFile = File("/Users/home/Desktop/temp11111.jpg");

// Export an image of the page to disk
doc.exportFile(ExportFormat.jpg, tempFile);

// Place the page image back on the page
var pageToPlace = doc.pages[0].place(tempFile);

// Remove the temporary file from the disk
tempFile.remove();
```

Comment: Very helpful Josh. I've added a couple enhancements to the script that I'll now add to my question text.